# Why wont replace_na actually replace the missing values using dplyr and piping?

Tags: r, dplyr, missing-data, coalesce

I have been struggling a lot recently with the replace_na() function when cleaning my data. I have two complementary variables and I want to use one variable (varname2) to supply the missing values for the other (varname1). I've been trying the following:

```
df %>%
 replace_na(varname = varname2)
```

In response I keep getting the error:

```
Did you misspecify an argument?
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
> df <- df %>% 
+    replace_na(varname1= varname2)
Error: 1 components of `...` were not used.

We detected these problematic arguments:
* `varname1`
```

Suggestions for an efficient way to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I found a blog response elsewhere in which Hadley himself said they wanted to move away from `replace_na()` toward a more SQL adjacent command `coalesce()`. The solution involves both `across()` and `coalesce()`.

Here's an example of what I just did in my work:

```
df %>%
  mutate(across(varname1, coalesce, varname2))
```

It seems to have worked like a charm.